# Angularjs calling a controller function from a directive doesn't allow me to access $scope (sometimes)

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to pass a controller function to a directive, call that method, and modify the $scope on the controller. It works in the first case, but not in the second. I have three directives - oe-csv-parse, oe-csv-upload, and oe-csv-confirm:

```
appDirectives.directive('oeCsvParse', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
           onCsvParse: '&'
        },
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
            var uploadElement;

            this.addUploadElement = function(element) {
                uploadElement = element;
            };

            this.onOeConfirm = function() {
                $(uploadElement).parse({
                    config: {
                        complete: function(results) {
                            $scope.onCsvParse({rows: results.data});
                        }
                    }
                });
            };
        }]
    }
});

appDirectives.directive('oeCsvUpload', function() {
    return {
        require: '^oeCsvParse',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, csvParseCtrl) {
           csvParseCtrl.addUploadElement(element);
        }
    }
});

appDirectives.directive('oeCsvConfirm', function() {
    return {
        require: '^oeCsvParse',
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, csvParseCtrl) {
            this.csvParseCtrl = csvParseCtrl;
            $(element).click(function() {
                csvParseCtrl.onOeConfirm();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

When oe-csv-confirm is clicked, it calls onOeConfirm, which calls the function we passed in. I have two places where I use these directives. The first is:

```
.modal.hide.fade{ 'oe-csv-parse' => '', 'on-csv-parse' => 'onCsvParse(rows)' }
  .modal-body
    %input{ 'oe-csv-upload' => '', type: 'file' }
    .btn.btn-primary{ 'oe-csv-confirm' => '', 'data-dismiss' => 'modal' }
```

And the controller has a method:

```
$scope.onCsvParse = function(rows) {
    // From here, I can access $scope
};
```

In the second case, I cannot:

```
%div{ 'ng-controller' => 'UploadFinalListCtrl' }
  .modal.hide.fade{ 'oe-csv-parse' => '', 'on-csv-parse' => 'onCsvParse(rows)' }
    .modal-body
      %input{ 'oe-csv-upload' => '', type: 'file' }
      .btn.btn-primary{ 'oe-csv-confirm' => '', 'data-dismiss' => 'modal' }
```

The controller also has a method:

```
$scope.onCsvParse = function(rows) {
    // From here, I cannot access $scope
}
```

Any ideas what's going on here? When I call a controller method passed into the directive, when can I access $scope and when can I not?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since `complete` is not an angular event, you need to tell angular that an event as occurred, to do that, you need to wrap your event in an `$apply` call like:

```
this.onOeConfirm = function() {
    $(uploadElement).parse({
        config: {
            complete: function(results) {
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                  $scope.onCsvParse({rows: results.data});
                });                
            }
        }
    });
};
```

That way, when the event is fired, angular will be able to manage it, run a `$digest` and process what it needs.

That should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Yes, I should definitely be calling $apply from the directive. Unfortunately this didn't solve my problem, but I found that my problem was not really a problem.

I had a debugger; call in my callback, and was trying to look at $scope. But it looks like even though I'm dependency injecting $scope, It's only defined if I call $scope from my function! as soon as I added console.log($scope), I was able to call $scope from my console. Interesting!